# Reference existing expression

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access, how do I reference an existing expression in the builder?

I tried just typing it in as: Expr1, and I also tried putting it in brackets like this: (Expr1), in both cases, the number that came out didn't make sense.

Update:

Currently I have these existing Expressions

```
SELECT tblInventory.ProductNo, tblInventory.NewFSPrice, tblInventory.FSPrice,     tblInventory.FSMarkUp, tblInventory.Cost, [tblInventory]![Cost]/[tblInventory]![FSMarkUp]      AS Expr1, [tblInventory]![Cost]/[tblInventory]![FSPrice] AS Expr2
FROM tblInventory;
```

If it really comes down to me having to bracket these and then run them I will, but I would like to know if there's a way that I don't have to actually write them out again so I can use them in an expression that would be something like

FSPrice - Expr1

Comment: If this is in a query, you only have very limited options for referencing expressions. Please expand your question to include an example.

Comment: @Remou I have updated the question to include the existing expressions

Comment: Where do you have these expressions? In a query? Are you trying to reference them in a query? It is best to post the sql, if that is the case. You perform operations on an expression in a query as ling as you are careful about zeros and nulls, but you cannot use an expression in GROUP BY, for example.

Comment: OK sorry, here's the SQL view. (from an expression)

Comment: also, I'm not sure what you mean by GROUP BY

Comment: GROUP BY is for aggregates: `SELECT ProductID, Sum(Stock) FROM Products GROUP BY ProductID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my query

```
SELECT tblInventory.ProductNo, 
       tblInventory.NewFSPrice, 
       tblInventory.FSPrice,  
       tblInventory.FSMarkUp,  
       tblInventory.Cost,  
       [tblInventory]![Cost]/[tblInventory]![FSMarkUp] AS Expr1,  
       [tblInventory]![Cost]/[tblInventory]![FSPrice] AS Expr2,  
       [FSPrice]-[Expr1] AS Expr3
FROM tblInventory;
```

Returning

```
ProductNo   NewFSPrice  FSPrice FSMarkUp    Cost    Expr1   Expr2   Expr3
1           10          10      5           5       1       0.5     9
```

Note that Expr3 must occur after Expr1 in the design grid. In addition, I am not dividing by zero at any point, nor are any nulls returned, if there were, I would need to allow for that by using IIfs and / or Nz.

Comment: Thanks, I'm very new to Access and SQL, so I'm doing my best to learn the coding instead of running the Queries through Design View. This is a big help.